# Cannot set up robotframework for PyCharm

Tags: python, selenium, testing, robotframework

I am struggling with install robotframework.

I have downloaded and installed fresh Python 2.7.14. I have added it and scripts to PATH.
Next I have downloaded robotframework with pip (pip install robotframework).
Next I have downloaded and installed selenium library (pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary).
Next I have downloaded and installed Intellibot plugin for PyCharm.

Now I see that *.robot files are associated with Intellibot (robot icon) 
BUT

after I wrote this simple "test":

---

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  simple test
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
This is some test case
    Open Browser  http://google.pl chrome
    Close Browser
```

---

SeleniumLibrary in ***Settings*** is not marked as error. I think everything is good there.
There is no autocomplete for "Open Browser" and "Close Browser" commands. Both are with red underline and info "Keyword definition not found".
After I run this test I got error: "SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities" (browser don't open at all).

Need some advice here...

Comment: First, is that really your code?  You're missing a space between `http://google.pl` and `chrome`. Second, The PyCharm plugin has not been updated to account for the redesign of SeleniumLibrary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more of a product support question than a programming question.

Comment: Unninstalling selenium library and installing it again as "pip install robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0" helped and commands are no longer red underlined. Error still occurs though.

Comment: Did you put two spaces between "http://google.pl" and "chrome"?

Comment: Problem with one blank space after url solved second problem. Thank you Bryan.